# Updating ejs to newer version in Sails.js

Tags: npm, sails.js

My current version of Sails uses ejs@0.88. There is already a 2.0+ version out. How do I update, for sails.js, the ejs package only? Also is there a way to use a local ejs package?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do that since it could break your app because that version is a Sails dependency.

However, if you want to try:

1. Locate the `"ejs": "~X.Y.Z"` in your `package.json` file  (`dependencies` section)
2. Update `X.Y.Z` to the current version number
3. Run the `npm install` command
4. Check that everything is still working ...

Comment: Yes I am assuming we will run into a lot of issues. The problem I have right now is that the current version of .ejs does not support includes using variable names for files (for example include whatever filename the database sends, yes you could use "if, else" but that is not nice for a big list of possibilities)... the new version of ejs has this feature

Answer (score 2):

Update only EJS not working cause sails is not compatible (yet?) with this version.

Like the doc sails http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/views/view-engines#adding-new-custom-view-engines

Sails use [consolidate lib template](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/blob/master/Readme.md) and they work to be compatible with EJS V2 : https://github.com/tj/ejs

You can help them to make it compatible or create your own plugin to make it compatible.

Comment: Yes this is a problem because the current version of .ejs does not support includes using variable names... the new version of ejs does... any workaround to that?

Comment: Maybe you can try with eval function edit your question to add this part and some code about this please